# UICollectionView default margin whith UINavigationBar translucent

Tags: xcode8

i'm having problems with UICollectionView.

The first cell to be displayed has an upper margin of the same size as the height of the NabigationBar, but only if the NavigationBar is marked as translucent.

I show you some screenshots from my Storyboard.

When is translucent
[image: Storyboard when navigationbar is translucent]
When is not translucent
[image: Storyboard when navigationbar is translucent]
As you can see the cell has no upper margin when navigationbar is not marked as translucent.

HELP ME PLEASE :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the constraints.
The CollectionView top constraint was in relation with top layout guide, and must be in relation with View(superview), because "Top Layout Guide" changes when Navigation bar changes.